# Ampscript personalization not working in block

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am setting up an email for refund confirmations. I have this ampscript set up:

```
%%[
var  @payment_method, @paymentblock, 
set @payment_method = payment_method
]%%
```

Later on I have:

```
IF @payment_method == 'CreditCard' 
THEN SET @paymentblock = '<strong>%%cc_company%%</strong> account (account number ending in %%card_lastfour%%)'
```

Instead of displaying the values of `%%cc_company%%` and `%%card_lastfour%%`, the email displays the text '%%cc_company%%' and '%%card_lastfour%%'.

Answer (score 3):

That’s because you put it in `''` which makes it a string, and it’s literally displaying what’s in that string. Try using the [Concat()](https://ampscript.guide/concat/) function instead. I’d also set all variables properly using the [AttributeValue()](https://ampscript.guide/attributevalue/) function:

```
set @payment_method = AttributeValue('payment_method')
set @cc_company =  AttributeValue('cc_company')
set @card_lastfour = AttributeValue('card_lastfour')
```

…

```
SET @paymentblock = concat('<strong>',@cc_company,'</strong> account (account number ending in ',@card_lastfour,')')
```

Comment: You can also just output using the `TreatAsContent()` function when you want to display instead of `v()` and it should fill in the personalization strings, etc. as well since it processes it instead of displaying as string. For cleaner code, I would recommend @zuzannamj method though.